# activity life cycle demo: why can't Android studio run the project?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'am trying the activity life-cycle demo from android tutorial,

the sdk can't identify the symbol **R** and shows errors all over the manifest file.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRmps.png)

I opened the unzipped project file in the android studio, set the SDK to android in the project structure options.

And there isn't a **Gradle Script** folder in the bottom of the project files.

I tried find in sync with gradle in**Tools** and **View** options, there are no such options available. I tried Build options and bunch of other option.

I don't really know isn't there is a gradle stuff there in the sdk and if it is the only thing stopping the project from exucution.
 [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) is the link I downloaded the project from

Answer (score 0):

I found this temporary solution.

First, Create a new project in the android studio then, place all the `src` `res` files and `manifest file` in the newly created project with the demo app's files

Now replace the package directory with the current package directory in all the files.

That's it.